# Does the outfeed table have to be parallel with the rotating drum?

Tags: tool-maintenance, jointer

I realized that even though the edges of each knife are parallel to the outfeed table, the drum holding these knives isn't. The difference in vertical gaps between the barrel and the table is about 0.5 mm.

This means that I somehow compensated for this when I set the knives.

### **Can such a setup cause problems?**

[image]

I was working like this for quite some time, but I noticed that my knives chipped and dullened faster than usual.

This is a parallelogram jointer thicknesser `Proma HP-250 3-400`.

The cylinder diameter is the same on both ends.

The infeed and outfeed tables are as parallel as I was able to set them. The difference in gap is the same for infeed table.

Comment: Do you have that same gap offset as you rotate the cutter head around? If so, that means the cutter head is larger at one end than the other. If the gap varies, that means the cutter head is mounted off center. In the first case, I'd think it would qualify as "odd", but functional. In the second, I can't imagine how you'd get good results from the planer.

Comment: Some additional information would be helpful.   First, is this a dovetail ways jointer (probably, but need to know for sure).   Second, is there the same difference in alignment between the cutterhead and infeed table?   The short answer to your actual question (does the mis-alignment matter?) is going to be yes, but the the answer to the implied question, what to do about it, depends on the answers to those two additional questions.

Comment: @FreeMan - No, what you're saying is not true.   The only way the gap would vary is if the cutterhead is out of round, which is highly unlikely.   The source of the problem is that the axis of the cutterhead is not parallel to the plane of the outfeed table.   How it's fixed depends on the type of jointer (dovetail vs parallelogram), and whether the cutterhead is parallel to the infeed table or not.

Comment: @WalnutClose Thank you for your analysis! I added more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine is neither a parallelogram nor a dovetail jointer in the sense we understand the terms in the US.   No matter.   The key thing is that your procedure for adjusting the tables needs to start with making the infeed table parallel to the cutterhead axis.   I believe this is done with a stop on the right hand casting against which the jointer table rests when in the down position.  On many single purpose jointers, it must be done by shimming the bearing blocks for the cutterhead, but I don't believe that's right, or even possible on your combination machine.   As I don't read Czech, I can't be absolutely certain.  Once the infeed and cutterhead are parallel, then you adjust the outfeed table to parallel or co-planarity with the infeed table.

As your machine is now adjusted, your cutterhead is acting like a helical cutterhead with a very steep helix angle, and a single, long cutter that is straight-edged, instead of having the right curve to cut straight.   For narrow cuts (edge jointing) this will not make much difference, but for wide cuts, the blades are going to be cutting somewhat deeper in the center of the cut, and overall, I believe you will not be getting a truly flat result.

Comment: You seem to have found documentation for this somewhere. Including the link in the answer would be useful. Since your search-fu seems to be better than mine, maybe apply it to [this question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/13983/how-to-remove-a-table-saw-blade-held-in-with-a-hex-nut-and-allen-bolt) as well to see if you can help the same OP find instructions for that.